# Get radio button from Jquery collection

Tags: jquery

I try to disable one of the radio buttons by value. Is it possible to find a specific radio button inside a jquery collection (my_radios)? This is my code for finding the button so far:

```
var my_radios = parent.find('[name='my_radios']');

my_radios.find("[value='2']").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

I think something like `$(":radio[value=foobar]")` would work but i want to find it in the collection my_radios.

Comment: What is in the collection? DOM elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_radios.filter(":radio[value='2']").prop('disabled', true);
```

For this task you should use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method. Also note that to deal with `disabled` property you should better use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method.

Comment: Thats it, nice! The filter method exists to filter jquery collections right?

Comment: Exactly. From documentation: "Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.".

Comment: aw, you was faster than me... +1 :)